# How to render a js.erb with the same name as a member action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I'd think this would go automatically, as I have already managed to do so for my destroy action, but no JS in activated.

My controller action looks like this:

```ruby
  def visability_toggle
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @picture.toggle! :visable

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => 'visability_toggle' }
    end
  end
```

And for now my `pictures/_visability_toggle.js.erb` that I would like to match my controller looks like this:

```ruby
alert('Picture id: #{@picture.id}');
```

The action itself works. Also this JS is correct and worked when I added it with `render js: ...` in the controller action.

Comment: not sure what your real question is here, but if you want rails to detect your `js.erb` file automatically, dont prepend it with an underscore as if it was a partial

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned: I should have left the underscore out when naming my template.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { :location => path_to_controller_method_url(argument) }
end
```

How do you respond_to another js file in the controller using Ruby on Rails?

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
       :template => "pictures/visability_toggle.js.erb", 
       :layout => false
    }
end
```